# Cannot display/send data and image from Custom Listview to Detail activity

Tags: android, listview, detailsview

I'm new in android developer, I've problem in my **custom Listview**, the condition is when I click on my listview it should be go to detail activity. and yes, it works!
but the detail data and image isn't appear. only **detail.xml** without data and image.

**Ymainactivity.java**

```
private class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {     

    JSONArray str_json = null;
    JSONObject json = null;
     JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ListView listx;
    LazyAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data_map = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(YmainActivity.this);

     protected void onPreExecute() { 
         super.onPreExecute();
         this.dialog.setMessage("Memuat Item..");
         this.dialog.show();
     }

     protected String doInBackground(String... param) { 
         json = jParser.AmbilJson(link_url);

        try {
            str_json = json.getJSONArray("berita");

            for(int i = 0; i < str_json.length(); i++){
                JSONObject ar = str_json.getJSONObject(i);

                String kodebrg = "kode barang : "+ar.getString("kodebrg");
                String gambar = ar.getString("gambar2");
                String nama = ar.getString("nama");
                String stok = "Stok : "+ar.getString("stok")+" "+ar.getString("satauan");
                String harga = "Rp. "+ar.getString("harga")+" per "+ar.getString("satauan");
                String info = ar.getString("info");

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put(in_nama, nama);
                map.put(in_stok, stok);
                map.put(in_kodebrg, kodebrg);
                map.put(in_gambar, gambar);
                map.put(in_harga, harga);
                map.put(in_info, info);

                data_map.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null; 
        }

     protected void onPostExecute(String result) { 
         dialog.dismiss();          
         listx = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listos);
         adapter = new LazyAdapter(YmainActivity.this, data_map); 

        listx.setAdapter(adapter);

        if (adapter.getCount()==0) {   
            Toast.makeText(YmainActivity.this,"data tidak ditemukan",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        listx.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

                HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap<String, String>) adapter.getItem(position);

                String kodebrgs = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.kodebrgs)).getText().toString();                               
                Intent inx = new Intent(YmainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
                inx.putExtra(kodebrgs, map2.get(in_kodebrg));
                startActivity(inx); 

     }
```

**DetailActivity.java**

```
private class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    JSONArray artikel = null;
    JSONObject json = null;
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    Intent ins = getIntent();
    String kode1s = ins.getStringExtra(in_kodebrg);
    String link_url = "http:// my php file that call all data using primary id from table in my database mySQL"+kode1s;

    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(DetailActivity.this);

     protected void onPreExecute() { 
         super.onPreExecute();
         this.dialog.setMessage("Memuat Detail Produk..");
         this.dialog.show();
     }
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        json = jParser.AmbilJson(link_url);         
        return null;
    }

 protected void onPostExecute(String result) { 
     dialog.dismiss();  
        try {
            artikel = json.getJSONArray("artikel");

            for(int i = 0; i < artikel.length(); i++){
                JSONObject ar = artikel.getJSONObject(i);

                TextView judul1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.judul2);
                TextView detail1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail2);
                TextView isi1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.isi2);
                TextView info1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infobarang2);
                TextView kodebarang1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.kodenyabrg2);

                String judul_1 = ar.getString("nama");
                String detail_1 = "harga Rp. "+ ar.getString("harga");
                String isi_1 = "Stok Barang : "+ ar.getString("stok")+" "+ar.getString("satauan");
                String info_1 = "Info : "+ar.getString("info");
                String kodebarang_1 = "Kode Barang : "+ar.getString(in_kodebrg);

                judul1.setText(judul_1);
                detail1.setText(detail_1);
                isi1.setText(isi_1);
                info1.setText(info_1);
                kodebarang1.setText(kodebarang_1);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 }
}
```

**LazyAdapter.java**

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) { 
        return data.get(position); 
        }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)

            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listimage_item, null);

            TextView nama = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.namas);
            TextView stok = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.stoks);
            TextView kodebrg = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.kodebrgs);  
            TextView harga = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.hargas);
            TextView info = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.infos);
            ImageView gambar=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.gambars);

            HashMap<String, String> berita = new HashMap<String, String>();
            berita = data.get(position);

            nama.setText(berita.get(YmainActivity.in_nama));
            stok.setText(berita.get(YmainActivity.in_stok));
            kodebrg.setText(berita.get(YmainActivity.in_kodebrg));
            harga.setText(berita.get(YmainActivity.in_harga));
            info.setText(berita.get(YmainActivity.in_info));
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(berita.get(YmainActivity.in_gambar), gambar);
            return vi;
    }
}
```

this is my custom listiview pict

http://cdn.gudangimages.com/v1/2015/06/05/gambarlistview.png

and this is detail xml when I clicked one of the list in my custom listview the result is blank, no data and image.

http://cdn.gudangimages.com/v1/2015/06/05/gambardetail.png

I don't know what's wrong with the code, because when I run the program it didn't force close.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with `inx.putExtra(kodebrgs, map2.get(in_kodebrg));`
you should use key which doesn't change...

```
Intent i = new Intent(<currentActivity>.this,
                    <newactivity>.class);
            i.putExtra("ticket", ticket);
            i.putExtra("ticketid", tid);                                
            startActivity(i);
```

and in other intent:

```
String ticketid = getIntent().getStringExtra("ticketid").toString();
String ticket = getIntent().getStringExtra("ticket").toString();
```

you can also send each string with different key and get them in detail page with help of key.

Comment: thanks for answer, and I already tried your codes but it doesn't work and my apps get force close. this is the logcat :
06-05 13:24:54.425: E/AndroidRuntime(600): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3

Comment: are you able to log all values in Detail activity?

Comment: kiturk3 yes and there's nothing wrong (I think) in the log

Comment: so if you are getting log in you detail activity ther's nothing wrong with your adapter and onclicklistener.... just error in sending and receiving data from one activity to another.

Comment: correct! in my detail activity I use 
String kode1s = ins.getStringExtra(in_kodebrg);
String link_url = "http:// my php file"+kode1s; to get string from customlistview and json = jParser.AmbilJson(link_url); for displaying

Comment: yup... try sending and receiving as i answered above... It'll work :)

Answer (score 0):

first ,you need to debug on the detailActivity to find out whether getIntent() has got the data you desire , if you have got ,then use the view to contain these data ,if not , you need to think about whether the onitemclicklistener is ok